# Change web service namespace attribute according to web service url at runtime

Tags: c#, web-services, attributes, wsdl

My bank provides a web service to list bank transactions. When I add the web service to my C# project, the following class part is created. When another customer, lets call customer1, asks the bank the same web service, they only change the url and

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://customer1.genericekstre.driver.maestro.ibtech.com")]
```

I have to find a way to change namespace value by web service url at runtime, instead of adding web service for all customers. Is there a way to do it?

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.4084.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://omerharmansaekstre.genericekstre.driver.maestro.ibtech.com")]
public partial class QNBServiceException : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    
    private Exception omerHarmansaServiceException1Field;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("QNBServiceException", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
    public Exception QNBServiceException1 {
        get {
            return this.omerHarmansaServiceException1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.omerHarmansaServiceException1Field = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("QNBServiceException1");
        }
    }
    
    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to define a static variable to change the namespace but i couldn't do it.